# Get area of intersecting line (CGPoints)

Tags: ios, line, polygon, cgpoint

I have an Array of CGPoints and I would like to find those points, which build a shape. Please see the attached image:
[image]

The red circles just mark the points I have.

How can the area with the question mark be found?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the solution.

This function returns a polygon for each area that gets closed by intersecting lines.

```
func intersectionOfLineFrom(p1: CGPoint, to p2: CGPoint, withLineFrom p3: CGPoint, to p4: CGPoint) -> NSValue? {
    let d: CGFloat = (p2.x - p1.x) * (p4.y - p3.y) - (p2.y - p1.y) * (p4.x - p3.x)
    if d == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    // parallel lines
    let u: CGFloat = ((p3.x - p1.x) * (p4.y - p3.y) - (p3.y - p1.y) * (p4.x - p3.x)) / d
    let v: CGFloat = ((p3.x - p1.x) * (p2.y - p1.y) - (p3.y - p1.y) * (p2.x - p1.x)) / d
    if u < 0.0 || u > 1.0 {
        return nil
    }
    // intersection point not between p1 and p2
    if v < 0.0 || v > 1.0 {
        return nil
    }
    // intersection point not between p3 and p4
    var intersection: CGPoint = CGPointZero
    intersection.x = p1.x + u * (p2.x - p1.x)
    intersection.y = p1.y + u * (p2.y - p1.y)

    return NSValue(CGPoint: intersection)
}


func intersectedPolygons(points: [CGPoint]) -> [[CGPoint]] {
    var removeIndexBelow : Int = 0
    var removeIndexAbove : Int = 0

    var resultArrays : [[CGPoint]] = [[CGPoint]]()

    for i in 1..<points.count {
        let firstLineStart = points[i-1] as CGPoint
        let firstLineEnd = points[i] as CGPoint
        for var j = points.count-1; j > i+1; j-- {
            let lastLineStart = points[j-1] as CGPoint
            let lastLineEnd = points[j] as CGPoint
            if let intersect: NSValue = self.intersectionOfLineFrom(firstLineStart, to: firstLineEnd, withLineFrom: lastLineStart, to: lastLineEnd){
                var pointsCopy = points
                let intersection = intersect.CGPointValue()
                pointsCopy[i-1] = intersection
                pointsCopy[j] = intersection
                removeIndexBelow = i
                removeIndexAbove = j
                let fullPoly = Array(pointsCopy[removeIndexBelow-1..<removeIndexAbove])
                resultArrays.append(fullPoly)
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return resultArrays
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to start with your first line segment and check for intersections. Obviously if the first two line segments intersect then they are the same line and your shape is just a line, so ignore that case.  As you continue down your line segments once you find a segment pair that intersect then you have your shape.

Check line segment 2 against line segment 1.  Then check line segment 3 against line segment 2, then against line segment 1.  Then check 4 against 3, then 2, then 1, etc...  If you find that line segment 7 intersects with line segment 3, delete the first point of line segment 3 and se it to the intersection point you found.  Then delete the last point of line segment 7 and set it to the intersection point you found.  There you have your shape.

Here is an example method to find the intersection of 2 line segments (written in C#, but it's straight math so it should be very easy to convert to any language you would like).  [Taken from here:](http://ideone.com/PnPJgb)

```
// Determines if the lines AB and CD intersect.
static bool LinesIntersect(PointF A, PointF B, PointF C, PointF D)
{
    PointF CmP = new PointF(C.X - A.X, C.Y - A.Y);
    PointF r = new PointF(B.X - A.X, B.Y - A.Y);
    PointF s = new PointF(D.X - C.X, D.Y - C.Y);

    float CmPxr = CmP.X * r.Y - CmP.Y * r.X;
    float CmPxs = CmP.X * s.Y - CmP.Y * s.X;
    float rxs = r.X * s.Y - r.Y * s.X;

    if (CmPxr == 0f)
    {
        // Lines are collinear, and so intersect if they have any overlap

        return ((C.X - A.X < 0f) != (C.X - B.X < 0f))
            || ((C.Y - A.Y < 0f) != (C.Y - B.Y < 0f));
    }

    if (rxs == 0f)
        return false; // Lines are parallel.

    float rxsr = 1f / rxs;
    float t = CmPxs * rxsr;
    float u = CmPxr * rxsr;

    return (t >= 0f) && (t <= 1f) && (u >= 0f) && (u <= 1f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you pointed me to the right direction :)